# Pexpect: flushing output of spawn object to disk immediately

Tags: python, flush, pexpect, spawn

I have this code snippet to test zip archive integrity and writing the output to a file (stdout and stderr):

```
cmd = "gunzip -t " + crashFile + " > err.txt 2>&1"
p.sendline(cmd)
p.expect('\$ ')

f = open("err.txt")
```

However it always fails to open the file with the following error:

```
f = open("err.txt")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'err.txt'
```

But the file does exist. So it looks like the gunzip runs but the system isn't flushing the output to disk "in time" for the open to read the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like this isn't actually about flushing buffers, because once a process (such as gzip) has exited any internal buffers are gone and there is nothing left to flush.  Furthermore, the file will be created before gzip even starts, because it's part of a shell redirection.

Comment: But... what is `p`?  Is it an expect connection to somewhere... possibly another computer, or a shell running in a different location on the same computer?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. p = pexpect.spawn('ssh <user>@IP'). This gets me in my first system. Then from there, I do p.sendline('ssh <user>@IP') into my target system. which is Solaris 10.

Comment: The `open()` function opens a file on the computer you're running the program on.  The file is on a different computer, it sounds like.

Comment: Dietrich, you are right and it never occurred to me. I couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thanks a lot for the help.